# What is the official term for Photo Index?

Tags: orthorectification, internet-explorer, historical-imagery

I have a point shapefile that has all the aerial photos that were flown on our forest. However, they are very old and are black and white. They were scanned by our contractor. Their years are dated back to the 1930's to around 1950's.

I am not really familiar with the photo index and I have been searching around on the internet as I want to learn more about them. I want to know what they are for and how it works.

I have started working on them with my ERDAS Imagine 2016's AutoSync.

My question to you is when I google it, and  I have entered the word as  flight line or Photo index and it returned few results. Is there a official word/term that should I use to search for more information on google ?

Comment: Photo index, as far as I know it, is that one additional print you get when you get an analogue film developed. It contains miniatures of all the pictures on the roll of film. Maybe "index print" is what you are looking for.

Comment: Ok but do you know of a site that has rich information on the internet ?  Do they came from the Photogrammery courses that they talk about them ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Erik's comment, I believe I've also heard it referred to as a "contact sheet".

https://www.picturesandstories.com/news/2014/2/24/how-to-print-a-contact-sheet-of-photos-in-windows

Also, CALTRANS has a nice write-up of what they consider a Photo Index to be.

http://www.dot.ca.gov/hq/esc/photogrammetry/resources/Aerial_Photo_Index_Guide_2013v1.pdf

Comment: Thank you. So it said Aerial Photo Index Guide ..I will try and find these when I am google it. There could be different word from each person who works in that area.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you...

I think it is the right term to use "Aerial Photo Index" and I google and it came up a lot of information when you type it in Google

"Aerial Photo Index Guide"

it gave me all the results I was looking for ...